# Why am I getting [object HTMLDivElement] instead of the actual content?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');

cont.outerHTML=div; //tried with innerHTML too but didnt work either
```

but instead of getting a `<div></div>` it outputs this: [object HTMLDivElement]

I also tried:

```
div.innerHTML = '<div>hit1</div><div>hit2</div><div>hit3</div>';
```

but same result. Why is this happening?

Comment: Because you're attempting to set a string property with an object and getting the default `toString` of an object. If you want to append a DOM **element** you should be using DOM manipulation, not strings.

Comment: My html is a string: `<div>hit1</div><div>hit2</div><div>hit3</div>`. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[object HTMLDivElement]` is the result of `div.toString()` and is the default serialization of an HTML element.

If you want to add a child element to a container please try:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');

cont.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: but what about my html in `<div>hit1</div><div>hit2</div><div>hit3</div>`?

Comment: That should work as expected and result in ```div``` having three child elements.

Comment: How? Please elaborate.

Comment: @CainNuke Because that’s what `appendChild` does; it appends a child element.

Comment: When setting the ```innerHTML``` property of a DOM element the string will be parsed and transformed into actual DOM elements.

Comment: I need `<div>hit1</div><div>hit2</div><div>hit3</div>` to be the innerHTML of the created div but all I get is [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: Here's an example https://codepen.io/antonpodolsky/pen/MWBBwPK